# Searching for an analysis textbook

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks, mathematical-analysis

Particularly, I'm looking for an undergraduate text with an excellent explanation of $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ proofs, and many example questions related thereto.

Comment: Would you like to use this text as a student or teacher?

Comment: There's a large number of free textbooks on this topic: http://www.theassayer.org/cgi-bin/asbrowsesubject.cgi?class=Q#freeclassQAmg

Comment: Neither/both. I studied math as an undergrad and want to return to the topic after a number of years.

Comment: @QED: I think your question is on topic for math.SE rather than this site.  In fact if you go to that site you should not ask this question but rather search through the many questions about analysis textbooks that already exist there.

Comment: I see links to all these questions about math textbooks here. A sampling: "Best textbooks to introduce measure theory…", "Resources for teaching Riemann integration…", and so on. I think I'm right on topic. I'm looking for a text with certain characteristics, because I'm trying to re-teach myself something. Something about math. Here on "Mathematics Educators". It just so happens that I would be the teacher and the student. Which may be why you are confused.

Comment: Try this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298289/which-mathematical-analysis-i-book-or-textbook-is-the-best or similar questions.

Comment: Could you clarfify what types of proofs you are looking for. I assume delta/epsilon but then you rolled back to something that is not a delta (at least it does not look like that to me), but rather the symbol that is often used for partial derivatives. Thus, I am not certain what you are looking for. It could also help to include some more details on the context in the question.

Comment: Yes, I meant a little delta. Shows how long it's been. Looks guys it's not worth all of this. Close the question if you want. I've got a fine answer from Ben Crowell.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was honestly not sure if I understood correctly. I am sorry if you find the site not welcoming to your question. To what extent it welcomes questions from self-learners is a bit of an ongoing discussion and the site being new this is not quite decided yet.

Comment: I get the impression that you guys do indeed already have an opinion.